# remaining indecies in list in c#

Tags: c#, indexing

I have a list of class 'itemset' which I call it frequentItemsets which contains all frequent itemsets in a database and another list of integers which I call it 'index_of_sensitiveItemsets' that contains the indecies of the sensitive Frequent Itemsets in frequentItemsets list and it is defined by the user.

like this

```
List<Itemset> frequentItemsets = get_frequentItemsets_fromDB();
List<int> index_of_sensitiveItemsets  = get_senFrqItemsetIndex_from_user();
```

One solution to this question is like this :

```
        for (int i = 0; i < allfrequentItemsets.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                       if (! index_of_sensitiveItemsets.Contains(i))
                            index_of_nonsensitiveItemsets.Add(i);
                    }
```

but I am asking if there is a better way that gets the indecies(plural of index) of the remaining elements in frequentItemsets which are not in index_of_sensitiveItemsets list.

The class Itemset is loaded from spmf java library . It has two members : array of integer and integer support and a number of methods like this :

```
 public class Itemset : AbstractOrderedItemset
    {
        public int[] itemset;
        public int support;

        public Itemset();
        public Itemset(int item);
        public Itemset(int[] items);

        public virtual Itemset cloneItemSetMinusAnItemset(Itemset itemsetToNotKeep);
        public virtual Itemset cloneItemSetMinusOneItem(Integer itemToRemove);
        public override Integer get(int position);
        public override int getAbsoluteSupport();
        public virtual int[] getItems();
        public virtual void increaseTransactionCount();
        public virtual Itemset intersection(Itemset itemset2);
        public virtual void setAbsoluteSupport(Integer support);
        public override int size();
    }
```

thanks a lot in advance

Comment: looks like you need to show more code that's relative to your question what do the 2 separate methods look like..? what is the structure of the `itemset` class look like..??

Comment: Instead of storing indices of sensitive item sets I would recommend storing a unique identifier of the itemset. That way your code will be more robust and not prone to break if the order of frequentItemSets changes. This will also allow you to write a Linq query rather easily to accomplish this task.

Comment: @SquidScareMe - good spot - I'd just assumed that the index was the key (like a database Identity column). Good recommendation.

Comment: excuse me unique identifier like what ,I thought the fastest way to get element in a list is through index

Comment: @RationalRose - can you show use what itemset looks like (like DJ Kraze asked)? Thanks.

Comment: @SquidScareMe If I put an identifier how can the user knows of that identifier?

Comment: @RationalRose - I do not have enough information to tell you precisely how. This is getting into the design of your program and unfortunately I don't think this is the platform to handle it. I think for now the solution you listed above works for your immediate needs.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the ratio of sensitiveItemSets to frequentItemSets. If more than 50% of frequentItemSets are sensitiveItemSets it makes more sense to invert the problem and copy all the frequentItemSets to nonsensitiveItemSets then remove all those that dont exist in your sensitiveItemSets.

Either way, its unlikely there is a better performing code construct than the one youve written. Yes, you could use some fancy Linq to do it in less lines of code, but your code is unambiguous and easy to understand. I'd stick with what you've got, unless you can provide some further info which indicates that its poor performing in some way.